# Calling rest api in for loop and handle priority for viewable area using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-service

Am having a array which is having above 400 data ids based on this fruit id i wil run the rest api call in  for loop to get the relevant information of the each fruits.for small scale of list i can able to achieve but huge number of id's its failed to hit the api.so i have planned to hit 5 by 5 if one api call is done means then we should add one more api call in the loop.so problem here is i can't how to acheive this one and also  i need in case of user scroll down to some area means i should make api call for  the viewable area and wants to give the high priority for this.Kindly provide your suggestions and help on this.Following are the sample code:

```
function getidList() {
              var dList = SessionService.fList();
           //dList have the fruit ids once its done

            if (dList.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i<=5; i++) {
                                       var data = dList[i];
//here i have call the service for api call//
         fruitService.getFruitDetails(data, sessionID, getresponse);



                }
            }
//following code is service
function getFruitDetails(){
                var Data = { SessionID: sessionId, fID: fruit}
                http.callEx('GetallListData', Data).then(function (response) {
                    console.info("api", response);
                    dataobj[response.fruit.ID] = getfListData(response.fruitData);
                    fruitListModel.push(dataobj);
                    return getresponse(fruitListModel);
                });
}
```

so the problem here is with out page hanging i load the page.And i dont know how to handle the api call as optimizable once it done with first 5 and next 5 so on.giving top priority to viewable area.kindly provide the suggestion and some ideas

Answer (score 0):

In regards with usage you can try to load data 5 by 5 like below:

```
function getidList() {

var dList = SessionService.fList();

var dlength = dList.length;

if (dlength > 0) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dlength; i++) {

        data.push(dList[i]);

        if(i%5 === 0 || i === dlength - 1) {

            fruitService.getFruitDetails(data, sessionID, getresponse); // not your function signature though

            data = [];

        }
    }
}
```

}

or you can load data one by one when part of element is visible in viewport.

Hope this helps a little

Comment: can you please tell me why are you using this condition if(i%5 === 0 || i === dlength - 1)? until get the response for first api call and second will not intiated

Comment: if(i%5 === 0 will condition the call to one for each 5 array elements using modulus function or i === dlength - 1 when the array ends if its length is non divisible to 5; each call will get 5 elements or less for last one. Not sure if you can do this with angular only.

Comment: With angular you can accomplish this for sure one by one per element, not discussing now why would you need 5 per call.

Comment: Hi @steve  in some cases api can failed to return data when its having heavy data  to avoid that scenario i planned to 5 by 5.And one more thing in your code why you are  emptying the   data = [];.

Comment: Hi Sathish, you should call API service when boxes become visible, if you have 5 in a row, you will have 5 individual calls at once and the problem is resolved.